# How to delete all the environment variables which are inherited from the parent process?

Tags: c, linux, bash, environment-variables

I want to delete all the inherited environment variables,could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Find the next variable. Delete. Repeat.

Comment: Delete *inherited environment variable* even like `PATH`!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: delete the inherited environment variables and load the new variables,use execl("/bin/csh","-csh",NULL);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all environment variables in Linux with GNU C Library you can use [`clearenv()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html#Environment-Access). When this function is not available (it is not in POSIX) you can use `environ = NULL` instead. Do this before calling `execl()` or any variant.

If you are calling some `exec()` variant you can set the environment directly with the call (variants ending `e`) using the last parameter. Example executing `/bin/csh` with empty environment: `execle("/bin/csh", "-csh", NULL, NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unset all defined enviroment variables, you can do something like this:

```
for a in $(/usr/bin/env); do 
  unset $(echo "$a" | /usr/bin/cut -d = -f 1);
done
```

Note, this will unset `PATH` as well, so you might want to initialize the shell with a environment afterwards.

**Edit**
Shorter version inspired by @opentokix:

```
unset $(/usr/bin/env | /usr/bin/cut -d = -f 1 | /usr/bin/xargs)
```

Comment: As I have to run it in c language, should I run it as system("unset $(/usr/bin/env | /usr/bin/cut -d = -f 1 | /usr/bin/xargs)") ?

Comment: First off, have you tried? You'll get a nice hint from the system(3) man page, but if you actually try it you'll know for sure. Secondly, if you want an answer for C, then don't tag your question with bash.

Answer (score 0):

```
unset `env | awk -F= '/^\w/ {print $1}' | xargs`
```

This is probably not a good idea, since it will remove your path etc.

You can unset individual variables with unset VARIABLE

Comment: I run 
system("unset `env | awk -F= '/^\w/ {print $1}'|xargs`");
execl("/bin/csh","csh","-c","env",NULL);
in my child process,but I still get the environment variables,can you tell me the reason?

Comment: There are many good reasons why what you propose doesn't work. The first thing is that @opentokix code doesn't work. The `awk` command is wrong, it should be `awk -F= '{print $1}'`.

Comment: @BreakingDawn It essentially spawns a subshell, clears environment variables of it (the subshell!), and that's it. It does not affect the calling process *at all*.